# Center SVG <tspan> elements when surrounding <text> element has text-anchor=start

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

```
<text text-anchor="start|end">
   <tspan>Header line</tspan>
   <tspan>Sub</tspan>
</text>
```

I'd like to center the `tspan` elements relative to the width of the surrounding `text` element. I know that it is possible to do so by either setting `text-anchor="middle"` on the `text` or on both `tspan`s but I cannot do that since the `text` elements are pie chart labels which are positioned outside of the arc (position calculated with `2.2 * arc centroid`) and I have to set the `text-anchor` to `start` on the right side of the pie and to `end` on the left side in order for the labels to be positioned correctly. I hope this makes sense.

Could someone please give me a hint? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit strange that you have an empty `<text>` element with two `<tspan>`s. I reckon you want `Header list` as the text, with `Sub` as the tspan.

If that's correct, a possible solution is getting the length of the text with `this.parentNode.getComputedTextLength()`, positioning the tspan halfway that lent length and setting its `text-anchor` to `middle`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 100)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .text("Header line")
  .append("tspan")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dy", "1em")
  .attr("x", function() {
    return 100 + this.parentNode.getComputedTextLength() / 2;
  })
  .text("Sub")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Change the magic number `100` in the snippet above for the calculated position in your code.

Comment: Thank you Gerardo! Your assumption about my usecase was right and you helped me to attain a working solution. I could not use the code as is because `this.parentNode.getComputedTextLength()` adds the length of the first and second line (tspan) together, resulting in a wrong "mid point". I ended up using `this.parentNode.getBBox().width / 2` instead. I guess it might also be possible to use `(this.parentNode.getComputedTextLength() - this.getComputedTextLength()) / 2`.